# Drupal Webform Select 2 options instead of unlimited

Tags: webforms

I have a list of 150 products on my select a sample list on my webform. Customers are supposed to select only 2 products, not 3, 4, etc....

I chose "Multiple" so how can I have them select only 2 products from the list instead of 3 or more?

Thanks!

Comment: Just provide them with 2 select boxes that can only have 1 value each.

Comment: Thanks Beebee, the thing is that if they want to select 2 products from the same box, then they wouldn't be able to.

Comment: Found a solution! Webform Validation. Perfection. https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation

Answer (score 1):

You can do client-side checking for the number of items selected, and if greater than 2, you can add your desired behavior, such as clearing the selections and/or alerting the user.

Example with jQuery:

```
var selectID = '#your-select-ID'; // change this to your selector
$(selectID).change(function () {
  if ($(selectID + " option:selected").length > 2) {
      $(selectID).val([]); // clear the selections
      // do other stuff if you want, like alert('Can only select 2 options');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Leonardo! What should I add this code to?